# How to create a background processing android app using MIT app Inventor

Tags: android, app-inventor

is there any way to create a background processing application using MIT application. since it's a open source program, how can we contribute to develop this tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the App Inventor sources here http://appinventor.mit.edu/appinventor-sources, see also App Inventor at GitHub here https://github.com/mit-cml/appinventor-sources

and the App Inventor Open Source Group is here https://community.appinventor.mit.edu/c/open-source-development/10 to ask questions about working with the sources...